# Laravel saas one app multiple databases - symlinks?

Tags: php, laravel, symlink, saas

I'm trying to create saas application in Laravel 5.

What I need is one directory with main application. `/var/www/main/` - thats OK.

When I create a new client, new database is created, new subdomain is created, but I dont know how to create symlink to main application - but with custom .env file.

So I have: `/var/www/clients/clientA/` - in this directory I need .env file for this client but everything else is a symlink to main application.

Then if I open clientA.application.com - this clientA .env should be loaded and laravel should connect to selected client A database.

I tried `ln -s /var/www/main/ /var/www/clients/clienatA/` - but of course when I edited .env file, it was edited in main application too.

Can someone please help? Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in bootstrap/app.php :

```
switch (getenv('HTTP_HOST')) {
    case 'subdomain1.mywebsite.com':
        $environmentFile = '.subdomain1.env';
        break;
    case 'subdomain2.mywebsite.com':
        $environmentFile = '.subdomain2.env';
        break;

}
$environmentPath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
Dotenv::load($environmentPath , $environmentFile);
```

You can split getenv('HTTP_HOST') and extract the subdomain, and then setup $environmentFile accordingly...

**Another solution with .htaccess :**

.htaccess :

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'sub.domain'">
    SetEnv APP_DOMAIN sub
</If>
```

And 
then :

```
//own env directory for separate env files
$app->useEnvironmentPath( realpath(__DIR__ . '/../env/') );
//separate files for each domain (see htaccess)
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom( getenv('APP_DOMAIN') . '.env' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a multi tenant set up. Feel free to take inspiration from https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant; it might be a bit more than you need, but it solved the issue of overloading the configuration with tenant specific ones.

After a tenant was identified based on the hostname it would read custom configurations from a tenant directory and override existing configuration keys.

https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant/blob/5.x/src/Listeners/Filesystem/LoadsConfigs.php